# C# RegEx only replaces match if no other text in string

Tags: c#, regex

I have the following RegEx pattern:

```
@"^((\(?\+45\)?)?)(\s?\d{2}\s?\d{2}\s?\d{2}\s?\d{2})$/gm"
```

It's supposed to replace strings such as:

- 10203040
- 10 20 30 40
- +45 10 20 30 40
- +4510203040

This is my replace method:

```
var text = "10 10 10 10";
text = Regex.Replace(text, @"^((\(?\+45\)?)?)(\s?\d{2}\s?\d{2}\s?\d{2}\s?\d{2})$/gm", "****");
```

The above code returns "****" which is correct.

```
var text = "10 10 10 10 10203040";
text = Regex.Replace(text, @"^((\(?\+45\)?)?)(\s?\d{2}\s?\d{2}\s?\d{2}\s?\d{2})$/gm", "****");
```

The above code doesn't replace any text and just returns the original string - I need this code to return "**** ****", as there's two occurences of the numbers I need to match.

I hope someone can help me - thanks in advance :)

Comment: You've anchored your regex to start (`^`) and end (`$`) of line, so they will only perform replacements if the matched string is the *entire* line. Remove the anchors and it should work as expected.

Comment: Thanks! This fixed my issue :) please post an answer so I can mark it as the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've anchored your regex to start (`^`) and end (`$`) of line, so they will only perform replacements if the matched string is the entire line. Remove the anchors and it should work as expected.